# Emacsclient crashes when evaluating window functions

Tags: emacs, window, eval

To not bore anyone here with specifics, whenever I evaluate an expression similar to this one:

```
emacsclient -t -e '(set-buffer *scratch*)'
```

the client will flash up on the terminal and crash.

This seems to be happening with all window-changing functions. Is the client not supposed to work like that? Running this in a normal emacs session does not cause this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're also using `-t`, but I'm not exactly sure why.

Is your emacs running in another tty session?

Or is your emacs running in windowing mode (e.g. on X Windows)?

If I have emacs running in windowing mode and I run the following command from another xterm window, then everything works exactly as I would expect it to:

```
 emacsclient -c -e '(set-buffer "*scratch*")
```

Note in particular the `-c` option, and the fact that the buffer name is a string and so must be enclosed in double-quotes.

Comment: I run emacs-nox, so I need the -t switch to run it in xterm. It was the quotes though, I can't believe I overlooked that for so long -.-